# handling multiple Aspects in AspectJ

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I have a query, when im using multiple Aspects in my aop.xml. here's the problem. i have  defined some `<include>` and `<exclude>` in my `<weaver>`. i have 3 aspects in my aop file. i need to define a specific `<include>` and `<exclude>` for each aspects. how it is possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I need to use the most broad include so all 3 aspects can do their work. Just because you weave into a lot of classes, does not mean it will affect all classes. This is done in your pointcuts.